# DJ native swing jwebbrowser html parsing error

Tags: java, html-parsing, jwebbrowser, djnativeswing

I have an error htmlparsing .
I think the problem stems from the quotation marks DjNative language=javascript   error  language="javascript" I try all version of Dj native library

[Fatal Error] :2:18: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 18; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)

```
  private Document HTMLtoXML(String source)
 {
 Document doc = null;
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder builder;
     try {
         builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
         InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(source));
         doc = builder.parse(src);
     } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 return doc;  
 }

 public void StartTakip()
{   
  String htmlSource=webbrowser.getHTMLContent();
  dc = HTMLtoXML(htmlSource);   

 }
```

When I try to get page source code  a html page via DJNative Swing

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language=javascript src="/medula/scripts/capFirstLetters.js"></SCRIPT>
<TITLE>deneme</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor=#233333>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If  source like below,html parse is work well

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src="/medula/scripts/capFirstLetters.js"></SCRIPT>
<TITLE>deneme</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#233333">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with Jsoup-1.7.3.jar 
  Ex:

```
  JWebBrowser jwebbrowser=new Jwebbrowser();
  Document doc=Jsoup.parse(jwebbrowser.getHTMLContent);
```